# login jsf spring and hibernate error

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

i'm working on a login application using jsf, spring and hibernate.
I have a problem, i get invalid password and username even if i put valid username and password. i don't understand why. please help me :)

login.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <link href="http://localhost:8084/jsf/resources/css/login.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <div class="container">
        <h:form id="formLogin">            

    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" life="3000" />
    <p:panel header="Login">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel for="username" value="Username:" />
            <p:inputText id="username" value="#{utilisateurBean.utilisateur.username}" required="true" label="username" />

            <h:outputLabel for="password" value="Password:" />
            <p:password id="password" value="#{utilisateurBean.utilisateur.password}" required="true" label="password" />

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <p:commandButton value="Login" update="growl" actionListener="#{utilisateurBean.login(actionEvent)}" 
                                 oncomplete="handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args)" />
            </f:facet>  
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
        </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function handleLoginRequest(xhr, status, args) {
        if(args.validationFailed || !args.loggedIn) {
            PF('#formLogin').jq.effect("shake", {times:5}, 100);
        }
        else {
            location.href = args.route;
        }
    }
</script>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

UtilisateurBean.java

```
package controller;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.ActionEvent;
import model.services.UtilisateurMetier;
import model.services.UtilisateurMetierImpl;
import net.vo.Utilisateur;
import org.primefaces.context.RequestContext;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("view")
public class UtilisateurBean{

    private Utilisateur utilisateur;
    @Autowired
    private UtilisateurMetier utilisateurMetier;
    String route = "";
    public UtilisateurBean() {
        this.utilisateurMetier = new UtilisateurMetierImpl();
        if(this.utilisateur == null)
        {
            this.utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
        }
    }

    public Utilisateur getUtilisateur() {
        return utilisateur;
    }

    public void setUtilisateur(Utilisateur utilisateur) {
        this.utilisateur = utilisateur;
    }

    public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {    
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage msg;
        boolean loggedIn;

        this.utilisateur = this.utilisateurMetier.verify(this.utilisateur);
        if (this.utilisateur != null)
        {
            loggedIn = true;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("utilisateur", this.utilisateur.getUsername());
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", this.utilisateur.getUsername());
            route ="/jsf/faces/annee.xhtml";
            System.out.println(this.utilisateur.getUsername());
        } else {
            loggedIn = false;
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login Error", "Invalid mot de passe");
            if(this.utilisateur == null)
        {
            this.utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
        }
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        context.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
        context.addCallbackParam("route", route);
    }
}
```

UtilisateurMetier.java

```
package model.services;

import java.util.List;
import net.vo.Utilisateur;

public interface UtilisateurMetier {
    public Utilisateur verify(Utilisateur utilisateur);
}
```

UtilisateurMetierImpl.java

```
package model.services;

import dao.UtilisateurDao;
import java.util.List;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import net.vo.Utilisateur;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class UtilisateurMetierImpl implements UtilisateurMetier{

    @Autowired
    private UtilisateurDao dao;


    public void setDao(UtilisateurDao dao) {
        this.dao = dao;
    }
    @Override
    public Utilisateur verify(Utilisateur utilisateur)
    {
       return dao.verify(utilisateur);
    }
}
```

UtilisateurDao.java

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;
import net.vo.Utilisateur;

public interface UtilisateurDao {

    public Utilisateur getUtilisateur(Integer id);
    public Utilisateur verify(Utilisateur utilisateur);
}
```

UtilisateurHibernateDao.java

```
package dao;

import java.util.List;
import net.vo.Utilisateur;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class UtilisateurHibernateDao implements UtilisateurDao{
    private List<Utilisateur> listeUtilisateurs;
@Override
public Utilisateur getUtilisateur(Integer id) {
   Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
   try
   {
       session.beginTransaction();
       Query q = session.createQuery("from Utilisateur as u where u.idUtilisateur=" + id);
       return (Utilisateur) q.uniqueResult();
   }
   finally
   {
       session.close();
   }
}

@Override
public Utilisateur verify(Utilisateur utilisateur) {

    Utilisateur user = this.getUtilisateur(utilisateur.getIdUtilisateur());
    if(user != null)
    {
        if(!utilisateur.getPassword().equals(user.getPassword()))
        {
            user = null;
        }
    }
    return user;
}

}
```

Utilisateur.java

```
package net.vo;
// Generated 21 mai 2014 21:08:45 by Hibernate Tools 3.6.0



/**
 * Utilisateur generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Utilisateur  implements java.io.Serializable {


     private int idUtilisateur;
     private String username;
     private String password;

    public Utilisateur() {
    }

    public Utilisateur(int idUtilisateur, String username, String password) {
       this.idUtilisateur = idUtilisateur;
       this.username = username;
       this.password = password;
    }

    public int getIdUtilisateur() {
        return this.idUtilisateur;
    }

    public void setIdUtilisateur(int idUtilisateur) {
        this.idUtilisateur = idUtilisateur;
    }
    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return this.password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**edit**

```
 public void login(ActionEvent actionEvent)
    {    
        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
        FacesMessage msg;
        boolean loggedIn;

        this.utilisateur = this.utilisateurMetier.verify(this.utilisateur);
        if (this.utilisateur != null)
        {
            loggedIn = true;
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().put("utilisateur", this.utilisateur.getUsername());
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Welcome", this.utilisateur.getUsername());
            route ="/jsf/faces/index.xhtml";
            System.out.println(this.utilisateur.getUsername());
        } else {
            loggedIn = false;
            msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN, "Login Error", "Invalid mot de passe");
             if(this.utilisateur == null)
            {
                this.utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
            }
        }
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        context.addCallbackParam("loggedIn", loggedIn);
        context.addCallbackParam("route", route);

    }
```

Comment: Is your password encrypted in database or something like that?

Comment: You should not post *please specific user help me* within your question, it is considered wrong in this site.

Comment: no, the password is not encrypted. i have a table named utilisateur which has 3 fields : idUtilisateur, username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UtilisateurHibernateDao#verify` you're trying to retrieve the user from its id:

```
Utilisateur user = this.getUtilisateur(utilisateur.getIdUtilisateur());
```

But you only have the username ans password. I suggest to create another method that can return the user from its username:

```
public Utilisateur getUtilisateurByUsername(String username) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        Query q = session.createQuery("from Utilisateur as u where u.username=:username")
            .setString("username", username);
        return (Utilisateur) q.uniqueResult();
    }
    finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

And use this method in `verify`:

```
Utilisateur user = this.getUtilisateurByUsername(utilisateur.getUsername());
//rest of the code...
```

---

Not part of the main problem but IMO the `verify` method should be at service level, not at dao. Data Access Objects are meant to only retrieve and update the data to the data source, while the business rules should be in service layer.

Comment: thank you it worked, even though i already try it but it didn't work, but now it's good and for your advice about the business layer, i will do that. i have another problem, i want that if i put wrong username and password to be able to try to login another time until you get the right one. i think i did that on the code but it doesn't work. @Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: @Marina that should be validated in the service layer. If you search the user by its name but the dao returns a `null` value, then you already know the username is wrong, so you can return a proper message.

Comment: no, it's not that i want to return a message, what i want is to be able to login one more time when i click on the command button

Comment: @Marina the problem is that you assign the result of `verify` to the current `Utilisateur utilisateur` used in the managed bean, but when it is invalid you return `null`, then you will have a Target unreachable error (that appears in the log). So, to fix it, just check if the `Utilisateur utilisateur` is `null` and assign a new value to this variable.

Comment: i'm doing this in the bean  if(this.utilisateur == null)
        {
            this.utilisateur = new Utilisateur();
        } but i don't know it doesn't work.

Comment: @Marina add that code at the bottom of `login` method in our managed bean.

Comment: that didn't work, i've edited the question you can see it. @ Luiggi Mendoza

Comment: @Marina please check the log when you try to login for second time. Edit your post and add the log errors accordingly.

Comment: there is no log errors in the log, it's like nothing happens when i click the second time

Comment: @Marina then seems like a problem in the JavaScript.

Comment: ok, i will see it ven though i don't really understand javascript